# Applying pressure at an angle

Tags: pressure

When I apply the Force to an area , say at an angle $\theta$ with the vertical, is the pressure defined as 
$$ P =\frac{ \Delta F}{\Delta A_{Perpendicular} } =\frac{ \Delta F}{\Delta A \cos\theta} $$
Or 
$$ P =\frac{ \Delta F_{Perpendicular}}{\Delta A} =\frac{ \Delta F \cos\theta}{\Delta A}$$

And also please explain why , because both appear to be correct , but obviously give way different answers. Is it because the way pressure has been defined or some mathematical explaination too it too , because I get confused with these forms an often lot

Comment: A perp. Will be A/cos . No A*cos

Comment: @IshanJawale I didn't understand , please elaborate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The definition of pressure $P$ in terms of vector quantities is $d\vec F_{\rm n} = (-)P\, dA\,\hat n$ where $d\vec F_{\rm n}$ is the force whose line of action is along the direction of the normal, $\hat n$, to the surface of area $dA$.

[image]

In terms of magnitudes, $dF_{\rm n} = dF\, \cos \theta \Rightarrow dF\, \cos \theta  = P\,dA \Rightarrow P = \dfrac{dF\cos\theta}{dA} = \dfrac{F}{\left ( \frac{dA}{\cos \theta}\right)}$

Answer (score 0):

Let us think what you thought wrong while giving the first definition :- 
[image]
If you are familiar with the idea of area vector the you could send that the area vector $ A $ points vertically upwards in the plane of paper so to define pressure we need it's component in the direction perpendicular to the force $ F $. It would be $ \frac {A}{cos \theta} $ which would inturn make the first definition true.